# Firebase The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I imported json manually (json file). I get this error when I decode the json.

The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

where am I doing wrong? Is my model wrong? Is my reference wrong?

[image]

**JSON:**

```
{
  "allQuiz": [
    {
      "title":"Ağustos Test 1",
      "test": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "question":"Şekle göre aşağıdakiler hangisi doğrudur",
          "isQuestionImage": true,
          "isSectionImage": false,
          "imageName":"1.png",
          "sections": {
            "A":"2 numaralı aracın öncelikle geçmesi",
            "B":"1 numaralı aracın hızını arttırarak kavşağa girmesi",
            "C":"2 numaralı aracın 3 numaralı aracın geçmesini beklemesi",
            "D":"3 numaralı aracın 2 numaralı aracı ikaz ederek durdurması"
          },
          "correct": "A"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Model:**

```
struct QuizContainer: Codable {
    var allQuiz: [Quiz]
}

struct Quiz: Codable {
    var title: String
    var test: [Test]
}

enum TestSectionType: String, Codable, Hashable {
    case A = "A"
    case B = "B"
    case C = "C"
    case D = "D"
}

struct Test: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var question: String
    var isQuestionImage: Bool
    var isSectionImage: Bool
    var imageName: String
    var sections: [TestSectionType.RawValue : String]
    var correct: String
}
```

**JSON Decode:**

```
func getQuizQuestion() {
        let databaseReference = Database.database().reference().child("allQuiz")
        databaseReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            do {
                let foo = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(QuizContainer.self, from: snapshot.value ?? "")
                print(foo)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Could the getQuizQuestion function be faulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I don't need reference.

```
func getQuizQuestion() {
        let databaseReference = Database.database().reference() // here
        databaseReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            do {
                let foo = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(QuizContainer.self, from: snapshot.value ?? "")
                print(foo)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```